# php - file_put_contents doesnt work

Tags: php, html

im trying to use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) to write a file (an agreement content) so it can be edited by back-end admins.

```
<?php $agreement = file_get_contents('xxxx.txt');?>
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
<?php echo $agreement; ?>
</textarea>
```

at this point, the #agreement value return right and it shows right html elements displayed on the textarea (rich-text-editor)

my php file (submit action)

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
  {
    if ( ( !is_string($value) && !is_numeric($value) ) || !is_string($key) )
        continue;

    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        $value = htmlspecialchars( stripslashes((string)$value) );
    else
        $value = htmlspecialchars( (string)$value );
?>
    <tr>
        <th style="vertical-align: top"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( (string)$key ); ?></th>
        <td><pre class="samples"><?php echo $value; ?></pre></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
}?>

<?php echo $value;
    $file = 'xxxx.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    file_put_contents($file, $value);
?>
```

In the line when i echo ed $value,
  it return exact thing i want (`&lt;h2&gt;Hello Worldwqdwqdqwdqa&lt;/h2&gt;`) to store/write into my text file,
  but xxx.txt file does not changing at all.
  What i've missed?

Comment: Have you looked inside your error log?

Comment: \xampp\apache\logs\error.log ? no changes, the last one is two days ago,

Comment: chmod 0666 on your file so that apache can write it ?

Comment: how to do that on window's xampp?

Comment: hmm, on windows you don't need to do it.

Comment: @Twisted1919 i was thinking that way. btw, i was following this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your textarea name is editor1 btw. you dont need loop, as you are looping `$_POST`, the $value will be overwritten by last `$_POST`.

```
$editor1  = $_POST[ 'editor1' ];
```

[CKEditor doc](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration)

Comment: however, in the end, the $value return right value i want, i just cant write it into the file

Comment: i though that this should be translated into htmlentities, so it will displayed properly later, but this way, it return into markup/html codes, and it works, thanks

Comment: now i got this problem, when the first form, i generate the variable ($agreement) with file_get_contents, but, after i edit and it successful, i return to the form, the form content doesn't change, do you know why?

Comment: try [set data](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData)